# Azure Function Setting autoRenewTimeout in host json file not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, auto-renewing

I am using Azure Function to read Message from the Queue which takes a long time and for that, I have used autoRenewTimeout in the host.json file but still, the message reappears in the queue while it is being processed.

My Requirement is to process the message for long hours below is the json configuration file.

```
"version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "serviceBus": {
    // the maximum duration within which the message lock will be renewed automatically.
    "autoRenewTimeout": "05:00:00"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "05:02:00"
}
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1191) help.

Comment: I have gone through the link and done the same way of increasing the autoRenewTimeout to maximum i.e. 5 hrs "05:00:00" but still the message gets reappeared in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have configured host.json using V1 Function reference. For V2 and later, the config has changed. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output#hostjson-settings) for Service Bus section and refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) for over host.json for V2+. Below is just a sample, adjust as per your need.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. To conclude the thread, would you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?